# One user with two reputations?

Tags: discussion, user-accounts

Noticed something strange on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737710/c-structs-dont-define-types):

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhzB1.png]

The user Trollhorn appears twice, once with 1 and once with 31 reputation.  His name doesn't have a blue background, even though he asked the question.

Not sure if this is a bug, just posting FYI

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They are two different users, at least in the database.  Click each user's name and you'll see it goes to different profiles.

- Question: [stackoverflow.com/users/**211455**/trollhorn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/211455/trollhorn)
- Answer: [stackoverflow.com/users/**211471**/trollhorn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/211471/trollhorn)

Both accounts were created today.  This is clearly a mistake by the new user.  Note that the "answer" is an attempt by the user to use SO as a threaded messaging platform:

> Ah, thx, now I got it ^^...

Answer (score 7):

In the future just flag the question/answer and we can merge the users very easily.

Answer (score 3):

That user must have made the question, created a user and later created another user unknowingly.

You did right by posting it here to bring attention to the mods so they can merge the two user accounts.

Also, you can send a mail to team@stackoverflow.com telling them what you saw. Right now, a mod is bound to see it and fix it.